# How to copy specific values of array to another array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have 2 arrays like this:

```
const arr1 = [
    {id: 1, qty: 2, checked: true},
    {id: 2, qty: 2, checked: true},
    {id: 3, qty: 2, checked: false}
]

const arr2 = [
    {id: 1, qty: 2},
    {id: 2, qty: 2}
]
```

I want to copy values of `arr1` to `arr2` where `checked` is `true` only, more than that if `arr1` value is already exist in `arr2` I just want it to update its `qty` not `duplicate` again. But my problem is that in some scenarios I got it duplicate and update at the same time. Below here I try with for loops.

```
const handleAdd = () => {
    let newArray = [...arr2]
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if(arr2[j].id === arr1[i].id && arr1[i].checked === true){
                newArray[j].qty = newArray[j].qty + arr1[i].qty
                break
            }else{
                if(arr1[i].checked === true){
                    newArray.push(arr1[i])
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(newArray)
}
```

What went wrong here, any solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const myAdd = (needle, hayStack) => (
  hayStack.map(
    ({id, qty}) => ({
      id, qty,
      ...(
        needle.some(n => n.checked && n.id === id)
        ? (
          { qty } = needle.find(n => n.checked && n.id === id),
          { qty }
        )
        : {}
      )
    })
  ).concat(
    needle
    .filter(
      ({ id, checked }) => checked && !hayStack.some(h => h.id === id)
    ).map(({ id, qty }) => ({ id, qty }))
  )
);
/* explanation
// method to add or update arr2
const myAdd = (needle, hayStack) => (
  // first iterate over "arr2" (called hayStack here)
  // and update each item by matching "id" when "arr1" (called needle here)
  // has "checked" true
  hayStack.map(
    // de-structure "arr2" to directly access "id" and "qty"
    ({id, qty}) => ({
      id, qty,        // by default populate both "id" and "qty"
      ...(            // if "arr1" has a matching "id" and "checked" is true
                      // then, ".find()" the particular elt and 
                      // update the "qty"
        needle.some(n => n.checked && n.id === id)
        ? (           // extract only the "qty" from result ".find()"
          { qty } = needle.find(n => n.checked && n.id === id),
          { qty }     // return an object with one prop "qty"
        )
        : {}          // if "arr1" has no matching "id", no change to "arr2" elt
      )
    })
  ).concat(
    // concat items in "arr1" which are not already present in "arr2"
    // and have "checked" as "true"
    needle
    .filter(      // first filter only "new" items
      ({ id, checked }) => checked && !hayStack.some(h => h.id === id)
    ).map(        // destructure to extract only "id" and "qty" props
      ({ id, qty }) => ({ id, qty })
    )
  )
);
*/
const arr1 = [
    {id: 1, qty: 3, checked: true},
    {id: 2, qty: 2, checked: true},
    {id: 3, qty: 2, checked: false},
    {id: 4, qty: 4, checked: true}
];

const arr2 = [
    {id: 1, qty: 2},
    {id: 2, qty: 2}
];

console.log(
  'add/update elements from arr1:\n',
  JSON.stringify(arr1),
  '\n\ninto arr2: ',
  JSON.stringify(arr2),
  '\n\n',
  myAdd(arr1, arr2)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

Comment: Please do not use the above solution if the array sizes are significantly high. This solution employs ".find()" within an iteration - which is not optimal. Please refer to [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)'s [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72906525/13658816) which employs an object.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
}else {
    if (arr1[i].checked === true) {
        newArray.push(arr1[i])
        break
```

You're pushing to `newArray` if an item is checked *before iterating all the way through* the second array. If the first array's item is checked, then no matter what's in the second array, you will only check what's in `arr2[0]` before breaking in one of the branches - which will screw up your logic.

How about grouping up the second array by ID first? It'll make more sense at a glance and will also reduce the computational complexity.

```js
const arr1 = [
    {id: 1, qty: 2, checked: true},
    {id: 2, qty: 2, checked: true},
    {id: 3, qty: 2, checked: false}
]

const arr2 = [
    {id: 1, qty: 2},
    {id: 2, qty: 2}
]
const handleAdd = () => {
    const qtyById = Object.fromEntries(
      arr2.map(({ id, qty }) => [id, qty])
    );
    for (const item of arr1) {
      if (item.checked) {
        qtyById[item.id] = (qtyById[item.id] || 0) + item.qty;
      }
    }
    const newArray = Object.entries(qtyById).map(([id, qty]) => ({ id, qty }));
    console.log(newArray)
}

handleAdd();
```

If the order of `arr2` must be preserved and the items may not be in ascending numerical order, use a Map instead of an object so that the order of IDs is preserved in insertion order.

Comment: I have one more question? What if I have more object values except `id` and `qty`, example: I have object like `{id: 1, name: "xxx", qty: 2, checked: true},` how can `name` value copy to `arr2` too.

Comment: Change the `qtyById` object so that its values are not just the quantity, but an object containing the quantity and name. This'll require an extra statement at the beginning of a loop iteration to create the object if it doesn't exist yet. `qtyById[item.id] ??= { id, qty, name };`